# How to resolve ServiceLocator.Current is null using VSTO and MEF

Tags: c#, .net, prism, mef, service-locator

Using MEF in a VSTO project and defined container as follows

```
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(this.GetType().Assembly));
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(...);

        container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
```

all's working well using various libraries except where the code uses

```
 ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyInterface>()
```

which ofcourse throws a NullReferenceException

Considering ServiceLocator is in it's own dll, wondering how to wire it up or is it even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you could try this, where you define your container:

```
var mefAdapter = new MefServiceLocatorAdapter(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( () => mefAdapter);
```

The MefServiceLocatorAdapter is in the Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions namespace.

****EDIT:**
But remember that using ServiceLocator is considered an anti-pattern, and defeats the purpose of IoC/DI.